# Use AWS CLI profile for specific node program's context

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have several AWS profile that I use for managing different projects.
Let's call the default one "user1", and the one I want to use "user2"

So if I just do a `aws s3 ls` it gives me user1's info of course, or if I do `aws s3 ls --profile=user2` it gives me user2's, all good here

I also know that I can do `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2` then `aws s3 ls`, which correctly gives me user2's buckets

The problem is, I have a Node application that when I run locally I want to use user2's profile. I've tried all manner of `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2 npm run dev` and such but can't figure out how to do it?

**Question** How can I run a local Node program and have its AWS SDK use my desired profile?

Comment: In particular, you only want it to run for the node program, and nothing else?

Comment: @PrestonM Not necessarily no, it can run for the whole shell session or whatever that's cool too

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using the node aws sdk within your application? What kind of commands are you using, and what type of error is it giving you? It may be possible that 1. You are operating in the incorrect region. 2. You are specifying a command you don't have access to.

Comment: Thanks @PrestonM perhaps I wasn't clear in my question though, I wasn't getting any errors or anything I just wanted to use a different AWS profile to run that one app. Mohit's answer below solved my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should normally work like below. You need to pass the profile name beforehand.

```
AWS_PROFILE=user1 node script.js
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html